# node.js instantiate class multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have a class file that creates socket connections based on the parameter passed in during instantiate.

When I try to instantiate this file multiple times (for loop) it looks like the node.js is handling it like singleton.

Is there a way I can create new instances from a same js file that can hold its own arguments passed?

app.js

```
for(var i....){
    require('./controller/sockets')(param[i]);
}
```

./controller/sockets

```
var util = require('util');
var param

Socket = function(iParam) {
    param = iParam;
};

util.inherits(Socket,EventEmitter);

Socket.prototype.test = function(){
    return param;
};

module.exports = Socket;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show relevant code.  This is not a generic issue - it's specific to your code.  In case what you're trying to do is use `require()` multiple times in a loop, that is not how require works.  Modules are cached.  You can have the module export a constructor and then call that constructor multiple times.

Comment: added code....please let me know whats incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't actually create anything.  All it does it store an argument in a variable.  So, when you call it N times, that's all it does is store a different value into the same variable N times in a row.

Your code is essentially doing this:

```
var param;
var Socket = function(iParam) {
    param = iParam;
}

for(var i....){
    Socket(param[i]);
}
```

It is not clear to me what you want it to do, but perhaps the constructor needs to create an object (probably using `new`), initialize it and then return it.

---

If you want a new Socket object back from each call to the constructor, then you can do it like this:

```
var util = require('util');

function Socket(iParam) {
    this.param = iParam;
}

util.inherits(Socket,EventEmitter);

Socket.prototype.test = function(){
    return this.param;
};

module.exports = function(x) {
    return new Socket(x);
};
```

Comment: I want to create sock[i] = require('./controller/sockets')(param[i]); When I call sock[i].test, I want to get the original parameter I set in that instance.

Comment: @user3658423 - what do you want to be in `var[i]`?

Comment: I want to create sock[i] = require('./controller/sockets')(param[i]); When I call sock[i].test, I want to get the original parameter I set in that instance.

Comment: @user3658423 - I added a solution to my answer.